# Can one measure BLE-RSSI or Wifi-RSSI from one Android device to another?

Tags: android, android-wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with Bluetooth low energy and I can measure RSSI strength to BLE tags from my android device, that part I have working. While scanning I do not find any other android devices.

Is it possible to somehow measure the BLE or Wifi RSSI-strength to another android device?

Both devices will run my software so I am able to create any service or call any API if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Today it is not possible to measure BLE RSSI from one Android device to another.  The Android BLE stack supports only the Central BLE (scanner) role.  It does not support the Peripheral BLE (beacon) role.